# Drupal 6 Layout issue

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

i have recently started to learn drupal 6. I dont have any previous experience with drupal.

I was asked to implement a page on existing drupal site with the following structure.

a sopping page which will have an thumbail size image with lable and a quantity text box. This pattern will repeat for 10 products. At the end of the page i should have a submit button which results in sending an email with product and quantity to dedicated email address.

If its just a form then i can use webform but the requirement is having an image for every product.

I am  not sure how to implementn this...can someone guide me in the right direction please.

This is what i am trying to achieve(http://dontikurthi.com/sample.html)

thanks for the help in advance.

Cheers
R

Answer (score 0):

For the image handling, I suggest [ImageCache](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache). If this is going to be a shop, use [Ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart). It's an extremely powerfull shop system with lots of functions and extensions.

It's hard to recommend a single way since Drupal offers many ways of doing it. I would go with [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck) (let's you create your own content types with as many fields as you want) and/or [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) (pulls data from many different areas of the database into viewable form, highly customizeable and on of the first modules to install together with CCK). Create a new content type with the help of CCK and create a view that displays this particular content type in a fashionable manner. That should get you pretty close to the image above.

Comment: thanks Dr, no, the site does not have shopping cart. Its just a product with quantity display for user to insert the quantity and send button will send an email. If i use Views, can it display forms?

Comment: No, it can't (without programming). When you want to use Drupal's forms, be sure to carefully read the docs http://api.drupal.org/api/group/form_api/6 and linked sites. What you want can't be done (at least not in my knowledge) with default settings/modules.

Comment: Using this solution you can only display form, but you can't process it easily without programing.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a form with webform, you add form components, and you can add "markup" type component: it describes itself as "Markup allows you to enter custom HTML or PHP logic into your form."

So, to add a picture above or below a form item, just add a markup and put the appropriate HTML in it.
eg `<img src="http://localhost/picture.jpg " />`